# Enum constructor takes in more parameters than specified

Tags: java, enums

I have the following code and I try to understand what it does

```
public enum ExampleClass {
    INSTANCE("nothing"),
    ITEM;

    private String description;

    private ExampleClass(String description) {
         this.description = description;
    }

    static{
         ITEM = new ExampleClass("ITEM", 1, "this is an item");
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. what is INSTANCE("nothing") ?
2. the ExampleClass only takes in 1 variable in the constructor, why inside the static block ITEM takes in 3?

Comment: This will not compile (which means that your second point doesn't make any sense since we can't reassign enum constants)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExampleClass` is an `enum`. `INSTANCE` and `ITEM` are 2 instances of this `ExampleClass` (called [enum constants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1)). For example, this would be valid :

```
public enum ExampleClass {
  INSTANCE,
  ITEM;
}
```

That said, you can define your own constructors for enum, like this one :

```
private ExampleClass(String description) {
     this.description = description;
}
```

In the same way as with classes, if you define a custom constructor, the JVM will not create a default constructor.

- `INSTANCE("nothing")` will be instantiated using your custom constructor.
- `ITEM` is not valid because there is no 'no-arg' constructor.

This would be valid:

```
public enum ExampleClass {
  INSTANCE("nothing"),
  ITEM;

  private String description;

  //Will be used to instantiate INSTANCE("nothing")
  private ExampleClass(String description) {
     this.description = description;
  }

  //Will be used to instantiate ITEM
  private ExampleClass() {
  }
}
```

`new ExampleClass("ITEM", 1, "this is an item");` is even worse : you cannot instantiate an enum with a `new`. Only one instance of every enum literal can exist and they are handled by the JVM itself.And even if it was possible, there is no constructor with 3 args so it would still not compile

Comment: The only way the OPs example could come close to working is if the constructor had a varargs parameter

Comment: I didn't write the code. This is a code in production and I try to understand it. I also don't understand it works but it seems like it did...thanks anyway